# Postman Keycloak issuedFor

Tags: asp.net, postman

I'm trying to make a request from postman to Keycloak for authorization test and still getting this error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "You must provide the issuedFor"
}
```

PostMan request parameters:
[image: request body values]

Postman bearer token header:
[image: bearer token header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ook i found the problem and resolved it. Keycloak does not give access to some type of requests when going out of the network. You must put it in https. When on your local machine, it does work but as soon as you go out of localhost to the network to reach keycloak, you must pass to https.

So what i did is, in my request url, i changed the link to keycloak from http to https and hence changed the port from 8080 to 8443 (the port for https serving). Hope it would help someone. Special thanks to @RossPresser :)

Answer (score 7):

I know you've already picked an answer, but for the ones landing here from a web search on the Keycloak's `issuedFor` problem.

The root cause of the error message shown is the typo in the parameter name "audience" (not "audiance)". That nowadays would make Keycloak to fail fetching the client ID at https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/3631618b245fa768bff7009b9e87d01dd4387fe3/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/authorization/AuthorizationTokenService.java#L330. Just fix the spelling and you should be fine.

For the record, the "audience" parameter is required in the requests to evaluate permissions as stated in the Keycloak's documentation for the Authorization Services: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_obtaining_permissions.

Comment: Thank you sir!  But setting "audience" myself in the args, it worked!  Thank you!
_______________
let urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket");
urlencoded.append("audience", "my-client-id-name");